# Protractor report: How to get or add Start time and End time of Test Run

Tags: protractor

I am using `protractor-html-screenshot-reporter` reporting plugin for tests. Anyway there is not in-built method to put **start time** or **end time** of my test run. Please help me to do it. Requirement is final report should have

1. Test Case name
2. Test Run Start time
3. Test Run End time
4. Total time taken to execute the test